# If the parent Object is not singleton the childrens  are singleton?

Tags: java, spring, singleton

I have a Dao which is not Singleton, if other objetcs extend from him, is singleton or not ? code example

```
<bean id="dao" class="parentDao"
        scope="prototype">

</bean>

<bean id="childrenDao"
        class="some.dao.extends.parentDao"
        parent="parentDao">
</bean>
```

the childrenDao is it singleton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: Verified through a test, the scope is also inherited from the parent bean and can be overridden by the child. So in this case childrendDao will be a prototype.

This is what is stated in the reference document:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions

> A child bean definition inherits constructor argument values, property
> values, and method overrides from the parent, with the option to add
> new values. Any initialization method, destroy method, and/or static
> factory method settings that you specify will override the
> corresponding parent settings.
>
> The remaining settings are always taken from the child definition:
> depends on, autowire mode, dependency check, **singleton**, scope, lazy
> init.

Comment: I'm unsure about your test, but what the reference document states is that scope is NOT overridden, but always taken from the child definition. See also http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/30772-does-scope-prototype-in-a-parent-bean-apply-to-child-beans and also http://springindepth.com/book/in-depth-ioc-bean-inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 <bean id="dao" class="parentDao"

    scope="prototype">

 </bean>

<bean id="childrenDao"

    class="some.dao.extends.parentDao"

    parent="parentDao">
```

I this case childrenDao will be **singleton**. I have tested it because i became qurious when i saw some confusing answers.