# Does child bean automatically become prototype if parent bean defined as prototype

Tags: java, spring

In spring framework, if I have one bean defined as scope "protoype" and it is a parent to another bean. Does child bean automatically become prototype?

Example:

```
<bean id="a" class="..." scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="b" class="..." parent="a"/>
```

What will be the scope for b?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it will be a singleton since it is the default scope.

> The remaining settings are always taken from the **child** definition: depends on, autowire mode, dependency check, singleton, scope, lazy init.

Comment: Initially I was under an impression this is true, but now. I updated answer after testing it out. Spring doc is misleading

Answer (score 4):

As specified in doc
: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions

> A child bean definition inherits constructor argument values, property
>   values, and method overrides from the parent, with the option to add
>   new values. Any initialization method, destroy method, and/or static
>   factory method settings that you specify will override the
>   corresponding parent settings.
>
> The remaining settings are always taken from the child definition:
>   depends on, autowire mode, dependency check, singleton, scope, lazy
>   init.

Answer (score 2):

From the Spring reference:

> 3.6. Bean definition inheritance. The remaining settings will always be taken from the child definition: depends on, autowire mode, dependency check, singleton, scope, lazy init.

Therefore, t will not inherit the parent's scope

Comment: Aren't you contradicting your self? your reference to documentation says scope will be taken from child. Isn't that mean scope will not inherit? I am confused

Comment: you're right - It actually means the opposite - it will not be inherited.

Comment: it also has been covered in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532371/if-the-parent-object-is-not-singleton-the-childrens-are-singleton

Answer (score 0):

In the spring official document, the sub type will inherit parent all attributes, attribute sub class definition will override the parent class attributes

If you do not specify a scope, it will be inherited from the parent

Answer (score 0):

Child bean will **not** get parents scope.